# Pygame and Pymunk Programm loads a bit with back screen and then closes

Tags: python, pygame, pymunk

I was following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNjRz31-7s0&t=181s because I wanted to learn pymunk, but then the problem that is described in the title occured. I´ve already tried restarting IDLE and searching for a solution online, but its difficult to find something because I´m not getting an error message . Can you tell were the mistake is?

```
import pygame
import pymunk

pygame.init()
display= pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
clock= pygame.time.Clock()
space=pymunk.Space()
space.gravity = 0, -1000
FPS=80

def convert_coordinates(point):
    return point[0], 400-point[1]
    

body = pymunk.Body()
body.position= 200,300
shape = pymunk.Circle(body, 10)
shape.density= 1
shape.elasticity=1
space.add(body, shape)

segment_body = pymunk.Body(body_type=pymunk.Body.STATIC)
segment_shape= pymunk.Segment(segment_body, (0, 25), (400,25), 5)
segment_shape.elasticity=1
space.add(segment_shape)

def game():
    global segment_body,segment_shape
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
               return

        display.fill((255,255,255))
        x,y = convert_coordinates(body.position)
        pygame.draw.circle(display,(255,0,0), (int(x),int(y)) ,5)
        #pygame.draw.line(display, (0,0,0), (0,275), (400,200),5)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)
        space.step(1/FPS)

game()
pygame.quit()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You already got a good answer, but I will just add that after I saw this question I have made an update to Pymunk so that a normal python exception will happen in the future for this case (will be included in the next release, 6.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am getting an error message:

```
Aborting due to Chipmunk error: The shape's body must be added to the space before the shape.
    Failed condition: shape->body->space == space
    Source:Chipmunk2D\src\cpSpace.c:423
```

(Note that `pymunk` is a terrible library here and not throwing a python Exception >:-( ).

`space.add(segment_shape)` should be `space.add(segment_body, segment_shape)`

I would suggest not using IDLE here, since it appearntly does not correctly redirect the error messages from `pymunk`. Use the Terminal to execute the script (or even better, a larger scale IDE like Spyder or PyCharm)

Comment: Thanks for your help and recommendations, it works now! The guy from the tutorial said that static bodies are the only bodies where you only have to add the shape and not the body but apperantly not :((or I just unterstood something wrong, my english aint that great).